# nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

I am facing an issue with eclipselink jpa.

Error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot generate variable name for non-typed Collection return type and an empty Collection value

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot generate variable name for non-typed Collection return type and an empty Collection value

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot generate variable name for non-typed Collection return type and an empty Collection value
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot generate variable name for non-typed Collection return type and an empty Collection value
    org.springframework.core.Conventions.getVariableNameForReturnType(Conventions.java:194)
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.getNameForReturnValue(ModelFactory.java:215)
```

Console:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.config.SpringWebConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryImpl(PersistenceProvider.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:313)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 25 more
```

I have following jar files.

```
jstl-1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.0.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
persistence-api-1.0.2.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.6.1-RC1.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.6.1-RC1.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.1-RC1.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql-2.6.1-RC1.jar
org.eclipse.persistence.jpa-2.6.1-RC1.jar
javax.json-1.0.4.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-jpa-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
```

My Springwebconfig is as given below.

```
package com.config;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.*;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.controller","com.domain","com.service","com.serviceimpl"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.dfs.myhrtest.repo")
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "eclipselink.target-database";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_JPA_MAP = "eclipselink.weaving";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_LOAD_TIME_WEAVER = "loadTimeWeaver";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(PersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_JPA_MAP, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_JPA_MAP));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_LOAD_TIME_WEAVER, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_LOAD_TIME_WEAVER));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
    }

    /*@Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }*/

}
```

Properties file

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.url=jdbc:oracle:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
db.username=jjjjjjj
db.password=kkkkkkkkkk!d

#Hibernate Configuration:
eclipselink.target-database=Oracle
hibernate.show_sql=true
entitymanager.packages.to.scan=com.domain
eclipselink.weaving=static;
```

loadTimeWeaver=org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver

I have tried with weaving = false/true and static. Still The error is same. Please let me know if any one needs more details.

It would be great if anyone can help me. I am stuck...